# Inconsistent behaviour of props for Number/String in Vue.js 2.5.16

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is a long term existing issue for me, let's say I have a parent and child component.

```
// parent
<div>
  // passing a dynamic value
  <child :param="timestamp"/>
</div>

// Child
props: {
  param: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  }
},
```

When the param value passed into child component, it should pass the validation.

however, it shows the error

**`type check failed for prop "param". Expected Number, got String.`**

If I changed the type into **`String`**, it still showed the error but in a opposite way

**`type check failed for prop "param". Expected String, got Number.`**

Would be grateful to know how to solve this issue, thanks.

==========================================================================

Sorry for not explaining very well in first example.

So in my code base, I pass a variable to child component, the type of the value is always `Number`, let's say it's a timestamp, so when I pass the value, the inconsistent error appears all the time, which really confuses me.

Meanwhile, I use `v-bind` since I pass dynamic variable to child component.

Comment: What do you use the `v-bind` in `v-bind:param="12345"` for? Right now it looks like you want to pass a data variable called "12345" of your parent component. If you want to send a plain old string, remove `v-bind`

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Do you mind posting your full code?

Comment: @BennettDams I think I didn't explain it well. Actually I passed a dynamic variable, which is in timestamp format, it's definitely not a static value, that's the reason why I am using `v-bind`.

Comment: Does your timestamp variable have a String value in at least a single moment? Like its initial value before receiving an Integer, or after getting the Integer value, do you "clean" it with an empty String? It has to be an integer all the time

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and simply solved it by passing both possibilties in the prop definition, so instead of

```
props: {
     myprop: Number, 
     [..]
}
```

I say it may be both:

```
props: {
    myprop: [String, Number],
    [..]
}
```

I realize this might not be a clean solution if the prop value has to be exactly of a certain type, but I think I just leave this here anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Just have:

```
<child :param="12345"/>
```

You do not need to `bind` that way.

See this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ryv49jm594

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld :param="12345" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
};
</script>
```

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <p>{{ param }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    param: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```